# How to sort through data in xml to export into MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, xml, sorting

I am creating an iPhone dictionary application.  All data (words) are being stored in an xml file in this structure: word, xml code, definition.  Is there a way to sort this?  I am looking for a way to export this xml into MySQL server so that I don't have to manually copy and paste each word and its definition.

yes, i am a super beginner so sorry if this is not perfectly explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML can be imported into MySQL as of version 5.16 but if you have phpMyAdmin or similar installed it may be easier to convert the xml file to CSV or similar if you are a beginner. If you do need to import XML data to mysql however, please see the following:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html - A list of the functions used by MySQL to interact with XML documents

http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2006/03/importing-xml-data-into-mysql-using.html - A decent guide about using the functions above.

Hope that helps.